# Interconnected ForegnKey

Tags: python, django

I have a task:

- To make a database model with essentially 'student' and 'group'.
- 'Student' contains: 'Name', 'student ID card', 'group' (**must be ForeigKey to Group!**)
- 'Group' contains: 'group name' and 'captain' (**must be foreign key to Student!**)

Now I have a collision - right straight it's impossible. So I did it in this way:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    std_ID_card = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)


class Captain(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student)
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
```

Do I have more elegant and correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    std_ID_card = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group')

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    captain = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name='%(class)s_captain')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the original structure impossible?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    captain = models.ForeignKey('Student')

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    std_ID_card = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Comment: Reverse query name for field 'captain' clashes with field 'Student.group'